# Import statement missing in code generated using OTC framework

Tags: otcframework, otcconverter

Scenario:

1. Created an OTCS script file with a copy-literal command to copy a given value to a field of type BigDecimal.
2. Executed a test project to generate the object conversion source code.
3. The code generated for above-mentioned command did not contain the import statement for the BigDecimal type due to which the compilation is failing.
4. Generated command from the etc editor as below:

metadata:

objectTypes:

```
source: ar.ndc_21_3_4.IATAAirShoppingRQ

target: org.iata.iata._2015._00._2018_1.airshoppingrq.AirShoppingRQ
```

entryClassName: IATAAirShoppingRQ__AirShoppingRQ

commands:

- copy:

  id: CP1

  from:

  ```
  values:

  - 18.1
  ```

  to:

  ```
  objectPath: payloadAttributes.version
  ```

  factoryClassName: CP1

4. While testing the Otcs file with the test etc-test project, an error occurred as below,

> ar.ndc_21_3_4.IATAAirShoppingRQ_org.iata.iata._2015._00._2018_1.airshoppingrq.AirShoppingRQ.otcs

529  [main] INFO  o.o.compiler.OtcCodeGeneratorImpl - Starting Source-Code generator. Please wait.......

560  [main] INFO  o.o.compiler.OtcCodeGeneratorImpl - Source-Code generation completed in 30.689166 millis.

633  [main] INFO  o.o.compiler.OtcsCompilerImpl - Completed 1/1 OTC compilation(s), Failed : 0/1. in 159.718292 millis.

633  [main] INFO  o.o.compiler.OtcsCompilerImpl - Compiling source-code files. Please wait.......

//Users/sabarishr/ARR_Projects/OTC/otc/otc-home/src/AirShopping/CP1.java:28: error: cannot find symbol

```
    payloadAttributes.setVersion(new BigDecimal("18.1"));

                                     ^
```

symbol:   class BigDecimal

location: class AirShopping.CP1

2359 [main] ERROR o.o.compiler.OtcsCompilerImpl -

org.otcframework.compiler.exception.OtcCompilerException: Source code compilation failed.

```
at org.otcframework.compiler.OtcsCompilerImpl.compileSourceCode(OtcsCompilerImpl.java:482)

at org.otcframework.compiler.OtcsCompilerImpl.createCompilationUnitsAndCompile(OtcsCompilerImpl.java:447)

at org.otcframework.compiler.OtcsCompilerImpl.compileSourceCode(OtcsCompilerImpl.java:401)

at org.otcframework.test.unit.OtcTest.compileAndRegister(OtcTest.java:137)

at org.otcframework.test.unit.OtcTest.runTest(OtcTest.java:82)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)

at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
```

5. While compiling the Otcs file, corresponding java source code is generated for each command etc, while debugging the same found the import for BigDecimal datatype missing, generated source is given below

Please help me to address the issue in the OTC framework.

Comment: Verified and found it to be a bug.  Please create an issue on github - https://github.com/frank-a-otc/otcframework/issues